# How to prevent container component from re-rendering when child component updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, redux

I've been trying to optimise an app by preventing the container component in the example below from re-rendering every time the child component updates. The app example only has one counter which is updated via a key. I've stripped the example down to just one counter although I'm using multiple counters in the actual app.

It works by dispatching an increment action every second, which updates the redux state. The container maps through each counter (in this case just one) held in state and renders a child component which just displays the count.

I've looked at using PureComponent and shouldComponentUpdate but couldn't get it to stop re-rendering and I'm also not sure if the latter is the best approach. From similiar questions I've gleaned that the problem might be that both the container and child component are referring to the same object in state and therefore are both updated. Sandbox example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-rubin-k1gxy

Container

```
class CounterContainer extends React.PureComponent {
  renderWatches = () => {
    //was some map logic here originally hence separate method
    const { counters } = this.props;
    const counterKeys = Object.keys(counters);
    return counterKeys.map(key => {
      return <SingleCounter key={key} mapKey={key} />;
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("CounterContainer rendered");
    return <div>{this.renderWatches()}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    counters: state.counters
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CounterContainer);
```

Child

```
export const SingleCounter = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      props.dispatch(actionCreators.increment(props.counter.key));
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  });

  console.log("Child rendered");

  return <div>{props.counter.counter}</div>;
};

export const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    counter: state.counters[ownProps.mapKey]
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SingleCounter);
```

Looking at the console logs, I'd ideally like to see the child component re-render every time the counter is incremented however the container should render just once (or in the actual app, whenever another counter is added)

Comment: You are subscribed in both components to the same prop `counters` list so any change will update all subscribed components, is the way it goes.